# How to initiate manual AWS Route 53 Failover when using Health Checks?

Tags: domain-name-system, amazon-web-services, failover, amazon-route53

I am using Route 53 with DNS Failover configured based on Health Checks.  This is great, but sometimes I want to manually initiate a failover.

How can I manually cause a failover, for example in the event of maintanence?  If I rely on the automated failover, it will take a number of failed requests before the failover actually occurs hence why I would like to do manual failover so that there is zero downtime.

Currently we have to manually edit the IP addresses, but just initiating a failover would be much better.  Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Note that today we set DNS TTL to 30 seconds and wait 30 seconds post DNS update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by inverting the health check status, edit the health check and go to advanced and toggle "Invert health check status".

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/health-checks-creating-values.html#health-checks-creating-values-invert-health-check-status

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!  You are amazing!

Comment: This answer will not solve the issue regarding cached DNS resource records.